# Injectivity of the modified Bessel function of the second kind $K_n(z)$.

Tags: bessel-functions

I found that $K_n(z)$ is injective for all real n in Wolfram page: https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/BesselK.html (scroll down to click Scope > Function Properties).

Is anyone aware of the reference (book, journal articles, etc.) discussing the injectivity of the modified Bessel function of the second kind?

Thanks in advance for your response and help!